# A simple C for loop not goes down to 0

Tags: c

My for loop is going down and stops at 2 ,

```
  for(int fadeValue = startingPoint ; fadeValue >= 0; fadeValue -=3) 
  //fade value stops at 2.
```

I would like it to go to 0 always (the `fadeValue` is not always divided by 3 )   .

How can i change it to do that ?

Comment: Whats the value of `startingPoint` ? Also it's not getting `divided`, it `subtract` 3!

Comment: `2 - 3 = -1` => `!(-1 >= 0)`, 2 is the last value >= 0

Comment: How is it that you have 2k rep and you can't figure this out?

Comment: I dont understand why you people are so bad to me. i am not stupid i know its 2-3=-1 , but i would like it to do the subtract before ! . also @netcat , YES ITS NOT DIVIDED because then it would go exactly to zero !

Comment: You mean "divisible", not "divided".

Comment: oh yea, sorry for having a different native language than English ...

Comment: What values would you want for fadeValue is startingPoint is 5, 6 or 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
for(int fadeValue = startingPoint ; fadeValue >= 0;
    fadeValue = (fadeValue==1 || fadeValue==2) ? 0 : fadeValue-3)
```

This ensures that there is a last iteration with 0 after one with 1 or 2, without making the loop infinite.

Comment: oh great thats what i was looking for ! i dont understand why is the hostility , if you dont know the value and if its divided by 3 , you can't go to 0 !